# Divide the chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose you have marked all the 64 centers of unitsquares of a chessboard.

At least how many lines do you need, such that they divide the plane in a way, such that no two marked points lie in the same region (part of the plane)?

My guess is 14, and I was told that that is the correct answer, How can I prove it? Please help.

Comment: Well it is clearly an upper bound, by taking $7$ horizontal and $7$ vertical lines.

Comment: There is a similar IMO problem. It goes along with "suppose there exists such $n$ lines, then the equation of the lines is $P(x)=0$ for a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$"...

Comment: I found it. IMO 2007 problem 6. The difference is that, the IMO problem concerns "lines passing exactly through the point", and the problem at hand is a bit more "unstable".
Earnest's solution is genius. He succeeds at stablizing the lines by border segments.

Answer (score 9):

#### Big hint

The centers of the chessboard form an $8$ times $8$ grid of dots. There are $28$ line segments on the border of this grid which connect two adjacent border dots. Namely, there are $7$ horizontal segments on the top border, $7$ vertical segments on the right border, etc.

There needs to be a line passing through each of these $28$ border segments; if there was a border segment without a line through it, then the two points at the ends of the segment would not be separated.

How many border segments can a single line pass though?

Comment: very nice, i wonder if one can generalize this approach to general curves say circles instead of lines